# knex select() returns before completing query in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, knex.js

I have a function like this:

```
function get_projects() {
    var project_names=[];
    knex('projects').select('name').then(function (a) { 
        project_names.push(a);
    })
    return project_names;
}
```

This function executes the return statement `return project_names;` before completing `project_names.push(a)` statement and what I get after calling this function is an empty array, even though my db has results (I can see this if i log within the function a())

Comment: Your question asks "How to do select * from".... and is the highest result in google when asking how to select * from knex. Unfortunately in the body of your question you dont want to select * at all... You specifically want to select a single column.

Comment: In case someone came here looking for `select *`, then `.select()` method without any params worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @NoSound, someone should correct the question.

Answer (score 15):

knex select() returns a promise so that you can continue the flow within then() function.

```
knex('projects').select('name').then(function(projectNames){
    //do something here
    console.log(projectNames);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Nodejs is asynchronous, so as soon as your line `knex('projects').select('name').then...` is executed, the line `return project_names;' is run. As you have found out, it didn't wait until it was filled with values!

The standard "return" at the end of the methods isn't a good programming style for Nodejs, which is event based. It has its place, but more common is a callback approach. Consider reading some tutorials on this new approach (I like [this one](http://book.mixu.net/node/))

You might change your current code to something like:

```
function print_project_names() {
  get_projects( function(names){
    for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ )
    {
      console.log(names[i]+'\n');
    } 
  });
}

function get_projects( callback ) {
  var project_names=[];
  knex('projects').select('name').then(function (a) { 
     project_names.push(a);
     callback(project_names);
  })
}
```

*NOTE: This is not optimized code*

Here, when you want to print the project names (unsure your real goal), you are passing an actual **function definition**, as the "callback", into "get_projects". As the events fire, once the results are pushed into the project names, the callback is called with your new list.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you can do this:

```
function get_projects() {
    return knex('projects').select('name')
        .then(function (records) {
           // already returns an array you can do other things here
           return records;
        })
}
```

Now you can do this to access the data.

```
get_projects()
    .then(function (records) {
        // do what you need as well, like send to the frontend using express
        res.send(records);
    })
```